# Setting MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero as the default rounding method

Tags: c#

I'm doing an app and I need to round the numbers ALWAYS using the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero but every time I do the rounding I've to write the following statement

```
Math.Round(xxx, ddd, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Is there a way to set the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero to the default way to the method Math.Round(...)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to set the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero to the default way to the method Math.Round(...)?

No, there isn't.

But you can write a helper method that you use everywhere which uses `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.

```
public static class MathHelper
{
  public static double Round(double value, int digits)
  {
    return Math.Round(value, digits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
  }
}
```